# jquery do simple animation after document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im a beginner in jquery so please bear with me.

Im trying to `slideDown` a series of image right after the page loaded (`document.ready()`).

This is my JS code :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".product_image").slideDown("200");

        $(".product_image").hover(function(){
            $( this ).fadeOut( 200 );
            $( this ).fadeIn( 600 );
            $(this).css("background","black");
            $(this).slideDown("200");
            //$(this).hide();
        })
    });
</script>
```

And this is my HTML :

```
<img src="Images/products/3.jpg" class="product_image"/>
```

The hover function is working perfectly, but the `slideDown` do nothing. It should be animated right after the `$(document).ready()` function.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set css to hide it first:

```
.product_image {
    display: none;
}
```

or jQuery:

```
$(".product_image").hide();
```

since `slideDown()` only works for hidden elements.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pvfp8/)**

Answer (score 3):

for slidedown to work the image has to be hidden so try

```
<img src="Images/products/3.jpg" class="product_image" style="display: none"/>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cSC5V/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, its too bad i can only upvote once